# Showing 4 Cards in one row in desktop, 2 Cards in one row in tablet version Using react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` and I have 4 cards which I wanted to show them in one row in a desktop version and 2 cards in one raw in a tablet version, Instead of all in one col. Here is my code:

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

<Card className="card">
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={skill.content.image}/>
    <Card.Title>
        <h4>{skill.content.title}</h4>
    </Card.Title>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Card Layout](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-layout) components `CardGroup` and `CardDeck`:

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import CardDeck from 'react-bootstrap/CardDeck'

<CardDeck>
    <Card className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={skill.content.image}/>
        <Card.Title>
            <h4>{skill.content.title}</h4>
        </Card.Title>
    </Card>
</CardDeck>
```